# Ruby CGI - вывод в браузер

Tags: cgi, ruby

```
require  "cgi"
some_text = "<B>This is how you make text bold</B>"
translated = CGI.escapeHTML(some_text)

puts CGI.unescapeHTML(translated)
```

Как можно вывести исполнение этого кода в браузер?

Answer (score 1):

```
print *html_string*
```

html_string - HTML-строка, которую Вы хотите вывести на целевую страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы вывести текст в браузер, как минимум нужно поднять сервер. В Ruby есть встроенный сервер, WEBrick, вот пример с его использованием:

```
require 'webrick'

server = WEBrick::GenericServer.new :Port => 3000

trap("INT"){ server.shutdown }

server.start do |socket|
  socket.puts "Hello, world"
end
```